# ¿Existe una función para interpretar etiquetas HTML en un PDF con iTex7 y .NET

Tags: html, .net, pdf

Recientemente estoy trabajando con un proyecto desarrollado en `.NET` y me tocó migrar un reporte que se hacia con `DocumentBuilder`.

Estoy utilizando **`iText7`** como posible alternativa (ya que necesito un framework OpenSource).

Hasta el momento todo iba perfecto! Hasta que me topé con que en la **DB** se insertan etiquetas **HTML** del tipo **ul, li**, para hacer viñetas, además de que los acentos los inserta de la forma **`&cute`**.

Intenté limpiar este `string` con un `remplace()` pero de todos modos requiero imprimir las viñetas generadas con **ul** y **li** y no sirve el `remplace()` para la cuestión de los acentos.

De que manera puedo resolver esta cuestión?

.NET tiene bibliotecas que me permitan hacer esta "**interpretación**"? y de ser el caso, habría problemas con `iText7` al insertarlo en el `Paragraph`?

Agradezco de ante mano la ayuda.

Les dejo parte del **código**:

````
```c#
//doc es de tipo Document()
//setParrafo(string p) retorna un constructor de tipo Paragraph(p)
//setParrafo(DataTable dt, string p, int j, 0)) este metodo sobrecargado es el 
//que inserta los registros de la DB con el dt, p es el nombre de la columna
//j y 0 son parametros para el tipo de letra...
//dt.Rows[0][p].toString(); es donde extraigo las etiquetas HTML que necesito 
//interpretar e insertar en el Paragrapth
doc.Add(setParrafo("BENEFICIOS ADICIONALES"));
doc.Add(setParrafo(dt,"BeneficiosAdicionales",j,0));
```
````

como resultado de estas lineas de código me debería generar algo así:

**BENEFICIOS ADICIONALES**

° Vigilancia...

° Circuito cerrado ..

° **Área** con reja ..

Pero en su lugar aparece el texto con todo y etiquetas:

**BENEFICIOS ADICIONALES**

````
```html
<div id="1">
<ul>
<li> Vigilancia... </li>
<li> Circuito cerrado .. </li>
<li> <strong> &Aacute;rea </strong> con reja .. </li>
</ul>
```
````